# Como usar a API do Facebook para pegar o link de compartilhamento?

Tags: php, api, facebook

Eu tenho um trabalho no qual é necessário que eu pegue o link de compartilhamento do produto na loja virtual do cliente e registre no banco de dados. Ele paga por compartilhamento dos seus produtos, por isso a necessidade.

Eu tenho que pegar `link/id` da publicação e posteriormente acessar alguma parte da API do facebook para resgatas as informações deste `id`.

Se possível, também pegar o e-mail de quem fez o compartilhamento.

Como eu posso começar a desenvolver isso em `PHP`? Por onde eu devo começar a estudar sobre isso na documentação do facebook?

Answer (score -1):

Atenção para

> *Ele paga por compartilhamento dos seus produtos, por isso a necessidade.*

Não é permitido pagar as pessoas por interações no Facebook. É contra os termos .
Se fizer proposta disto aos usuários em seu site, ele pode ser listado na blacklist e seus apps cancelados .

Recomenda-se utilizar as formas de promoção para produtos do Facebook para melhor desempenho .

O formato adequado é o de Afiliados. Neste caso seus usuários compartilhariam de livre e espontânea vontade mas seriam pagos pelo site por comissão e nunca por interação ou ação , de compartilhar algo ou curtir algo. E sim de INDICAR o produto, e isso sendo distribuido com o codigo do afiliado no link, ainda que através do seu site com botões de compartilhamento, é o que costuma ser aceito, indicado, feito, e funcionado .